# How to get notified when EC2 instance is recycled?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Amazon sometimes recycles (shuts down and recreates) EC2 instance due to various reasons, hardware issues, maintenance, etc. How do you get notified when this happens? I have tried several of the Status Check Alarms and they don't seem to get triggered. And the scenario is hard to reproduce as it's up to Amazon to decide when to recycle.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an autoscaling group of a single instance (min=1, max=1) an then subscribe to it's autoscaling events.  Here's part of a Bash script that I use for this purpose (it assumes you have the AWS command line tools installed).

```
# Create SNS topic and email subscription to receive notifications
SNS=$(sns-create-topic AWS-MyApp)
sns-subscribe $SNS --protocol email --endpoint me@example.com

# Create launch configuration
as-create-launch-config app-as-cfg_sm --image-id ami-05dd5c6c --instance-type m1.small --group app-sg --key myapp-prod-key

# Make an autoscaling group of one instance with the launch config
as-create-auto-scaling-group app-as-grp --launch-configuration app-as-cfg_sm --min-size 1 --max-size 1 --default-cooldown 120 --grace-period 300 --tag "k=Name, v=MyApp-Autoscale, p=true"

# Subscribe to all the autoscaling events so I know what's going on.
as-put-notification-configuration --topic-arn $SNS --auto-scaling-group 'app-as-grp' --notification-types autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCH, autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATE, autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATE_ERROR, autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCH_ERROR
```